# Randomly generated localstorage keys

Tags: javascript, random, save

I am creating something which will require many localstorage keys. Therefore I was hoping to use Math.floor to randomly generate a user key.

I have used the following to save the local storage key

```
var randomnumber = Math.floor((Math.random()*100000000)+1)
var randomnumberstringify = String(randomnumber) 

    function savebox(id) {
        var answer = document.getElementById('box').value;
        document.write(randomnumberstringify);
        localStorage.setItem(randomnumberstringify, answer);
    }
```

And the following to load the key

```
    function loadbox() {
        if (localStorage.getItem(randomnumberstringify)) {
        var answer = localStorage.getItem(randomnumberstringify);
    }

    else {
        var answer = ' ';
    }

    document.getElementById('box').value = answer;
    }
```

However as you can see the load function uses "randomnumberstringify". This is ANOTHER random number

So essentially you saving with one random number and loading another random number (which obviously does not exist

Is there a better way of using random number as load key and save keys?

Answer (score 0):

If your `load` and `save` calls happens in same browser session, and if your `randomnumberstringify` key exists in a scope that is accessible by both of your `save` and `load` functions, and will not re-created again for that scope, you should be fine using this approach.

However, what you trying to do is use local storage as a persistent storege unit, that means you want to access same data for given user on different page loads or different browser session in which, in every load, javascript variable space gets erased.

If your case is the latter one, you should use hash functions to generate keys, and use user dependent strings to generate hash functions so you end up generating same keys for same users each time.

For example, given that you have sha1 hash function defined in your JavaScript enviroment

```
var randomnumberstringify = sha1('username');
```

This key generation method allows you to get same key for same user everytime. And you'll have no problem setting and getting only relevant data.

Here :http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-sha1.html you can find a javascript implementation of hash function SHA1.